# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace Util

Tags: java, spring, maven

My pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I don't get this error when I run `Abc.java` class in eclipse. It is working perfectly fine. But when I am trying to run from command line I am getting following error.
`Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/util]`.
The command I am using to run my class is:
 `java -cp xyz-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar <package name of Abc.java>.Abc`

Comment: check for any dependencies with a provided scope in your pom.xml. Its likely that the jar file is not being packaged with yours.

Comment: expand the maven dependencies in the eclipse and see what you are missing when you export the project.

Comment: My XML file definition has `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">`. And I also checked the spring.schema.It also has `http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd`.